# Can't copy photo from IPad

Tags: ipad, photos, copy-paste

I used to be able to copy a photo from the screen by pressing on the screen.

For some reason it will not copy anymore.

Comment: Which app? Support for this is by app. (Also, if it is a 3rd party app, perhaps they removed support...)

Answer (score 1):

This seems unusual if you can reproduce this after holding the power buttons and then sliding to turn off the iPad.

Which application is this failing once you restart cleanly? Safari or Notes app ar good to check. Also, make sure it’s not text copy and just photos.

Sorry I don’t have an absolute fox, but since you didn’t mention and troubleshooting I figure I can help with some things to start with.